# Return average value of node in binary tree python recursively

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have a binary tree as such:
[image]

I want to create a function that returns the average value of the tree, which in this case is `(5+3+2+6)/(4) = 4`.

I do I preorder traversal, and here are my functions:

```
def helper(root, total=0, amount=0):
    if root != None:
        total += root.data
        amount += 1
        helper(root.left, total, amount)
        helper(root.right, total, amount)      

    return (root, total, amount)

def avg(root):
    av = helper(root)
    return av[1]/av[2]
```

However this code only returns `(Node 5, total = 5, amount = 1)`. It's like it only scans the `first` node, and I don't know why or what's wrong with my code above.

```
class btn(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anti-pattern detected**

You're already using recursion with state variables – there's no need to use reassignment to add more complexity. The other answers on this page have failed you by making the same mistake

```
def avg (tree):
  def helper (node, sum, count):
    if node is None:
      return (0, 0)
    else:
      (Lsum, Lcount) = helper(node.left, 0, 0)
      (Rsum, Rcount) = helper(node.right, 0, 0)
      return (node.data + Lsum + Rsum, 1 + Lcount + Rcount)
  (sum, count) = helper(tree, 0, 0)
  return sum/count if count > 0 else None

# your node class
class Node (object):
  def __init__(self, data, left, right):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

# make your tree
tree = Node(5, Node(3, Node(2, None, None), None), Node(6, None, None))

print(avg(tree)) #=> 4.0

# ensure that this works for an empty tree too (it does)
print(avg(None)) #=> None
```

---

**Intuition**

Recursion allows us to develop a really good intuition about this – specifically the **bolded** line

```
(Lsum, Lcount) = helper(node.left, 0, 0)
(Rsum, Rcount) = helper(node.right, 0, 0)
return (node.data + Lsum + Rsum, 1 + Lcount + Rcount)
```

That `return` is saying return a tuple of `(sum, count)` where

- for the **sum**, this node's data plus whatever the left and right sums are
- for the **count**, count this node (1) plus whatever the left and right counts are

By writing it this way, we can very clearly see the two cases our function has to handle:

1. When a node is `None`, we contribute `(0, 0)` to the final computation
2. Otherwise, we contribute the node's `data` to the **sum**, and `1` to the **count**.

---

**Inline code explanation**

```
# we only need to expose one function
def avg (tree):

  # helper isn't exposed outside of avg
  # helper has stateful parameters
  def helper (node, sum, count):

    # helper is a recursive function, start with the base case of empty Node
    if node is None:
      # our base sum and count are 0
      return (0, 0)

    # process the Node
    else:

      # get L sum and count the same way we initialized helper with the tree
      (Lsum, Lcount) = helper(node.left, 0, 0)

      # do the same for the R side
      (Rsum, Rcount) = helper(node.right, 0, 0)

      # no reassignment of sum or count is necessary,
      # simply recurse using the new state values of each
      return (
        node.data + Lsum + Rsum, # sum equals this node plus L and R sums
        1 + Lcount + Rcount      # count equals 1 plus L and R counts
      )

  # always init the sum and count with 0
  (sum, count) = helper(tree, 0, 0)

  # don't divide by zero if the tree is empty; instead return None
  return sum/count if count > 0 else None
```

---

**Cleaning up all the intermediate values**

Let's take a look at this

```
(Lsum, Lcount) = helper(node.left, 0, 0)
(Rsum, Rcount) = helper(node.right, 0, 0)
return (node.data + Lsum + Rsum, 1 + Lcount + Rcount)
```

If you're like me, despite the fact this is a huge improvement on the other answers using reassignment, it's still **4** intermediate values being used. It'd be nice if we can clean this up a little bit – and we can.

What if we had a function that could take a list of tuples, and add all the values in their respective positions?

```
// if only ...
sum_tuples( (0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30) )
# ... ( 0 + 1 + 2 , 10 + 20 + 30 )
#=> (3, 60)
```

Turns out that function is actually pretty easy to write with the help of `zip`. This function is operation is generic so it is useful in places other than our `avg` function, so I'll define it separately

```
def sum_tuples (*xs):
  return tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(*xs))

sum_tuples( (0,10), (1,20), (2,30) )
#=> (3, 60)
```

Now look at the effect it has on `avg` – no more intermediate values (changes in **bold**)

```
def avg (tree):
  def helper (node, sum, count):
    if node is None:
      return (0, 0)
    else:
      return sum_tuples(
        (node.data, 1),
        helper(node.left, 0, 0),
        helper(node.right, 0, 0)
      )
  (sum, count) = helper(tree, 0, 0)
  return sum/count if count > 0 else None
```

Of course it works the same as before, only now it's just about as beautiful as can be.

Answer (score -1):

You're not using the return values when calling `helper`. These should be used to determine the sum of values in the whole tree:

```
def helper(root, total=0, amount=0):
    if root != None:
        total += root.data
        amount += 1
        _, left_total, left_amount = helper(root.left, total, amount)
        _, right_total, right_amount = helper(root.right, total, amount)
        total += left_total
        total += right_total
        amount += left_amount
        amount += right_amount

    return (root, total, amount)
```

The following line "unpacks" the return value from `helper` into each of the three values:

```
_, left_total, left_amount = helper(root.left, total, amount)
```

The first of the three values is assigned to `_` but that's being ignored (the variable `_` is usually used in that case) and then there are `left_total` and `left_amount` which are the second and third values in the returned tuple.

Comment: What does the `_,` mean?

Comment: I see what you mean, but please explain that syntax above?

Comment: @VeeshaDawg I have expanded the answer.

Comment: Why didn't you just store them as `root`?

Comment: @VeeshaDawg well the value is not being used. We could even update the code to not return the `root` node at all as the first value (unless there's a reason to keep that code there).

Comment: using reassignment with recursion is a brainf*** anti pattern – the state variables are already setup to carry everything we need to know for any step of the computation – reassignment makes this much harder to read and reason about. keep it simple.

Answer (score -1):

```
def helper(root, total=0, amount=0):
if root != None:
    total += root.data
    amount += 1
    (_, total, amount) = helper(root.left, total, amount)
    (_, total, amount) = helper(root.right, total, amount)
return (root, total, amount)
```

You're giving the current total and amount to the helper functions, but you're not storing the new values they return.